# Translating a prayer

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I want to translate the following prayer from English:

> "Dear Lord, I pray that the Holy Spirit be with all of us, guide us in our studies and give us perseverance, help us to have patience with each other and with ourselves, and help us to keep a good sense of humor through it all.  In Jesús’ name, Amen."

The Spanish translation I have so far is:

> "Amado Señor, oro que el Espíritu Santo permanezca con todos nosotros, que nos guie en nuestros estudios, que nos de perseverancia, que nos ayude a tener paciencia el uno con el otro y con nosotros mismos, y que nos ayude a mantener el buen humor en todo momento. En el nombre de Jesús, Amen."

Does anybody have any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: We are not proofreading.

Answer (score 3):

I think you did a good job, just a minor retouch

The diacritic accent in **guíe** and **Amén**

> "Amado Señor, oro **(para/por)** que el Espíritu Santo permanezca con todos nosotros, que nos **guíe** en nuestros estudios, que nos de perseverancia, que nos ayude a tener paciencia el uno con el otro y con nosotros mismos, y que nos ayude a mantener el buen humor en todo momento. En el nombre de Jesús, **Amén**."

Comment: Also `Amen` -> `Amén`, `de perseverancia` -> `dé perseverancia`. And `oro que` sounds weird, I would say `oro *por* que`.

Comment: `oro` a mi me suena normal, pero es valido tu acotamiento

Comment: `orar` a secas a mí me suena extraño, mientras que `orar por` sí me encaja. Pero no encuentro referencias al respecto.

Comment: @fedorqui could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl si tienes alguna idea de lo que debo hacer en ese caso?

Comment: no creo que sea un buen *sentido del humor* porque esa frase se refiere a entender y soportar bromas, y en la oración se refieren a *tener buen humor* como a estar animado o contento

Answer (score 1):

"Oro que" does not sound right. Better: "oro para que" or "rezo para que". Less literal but more natural would be "te suplico que", "te pido que" or "te imploro que".

Furthermore, in my experience (catholic) it's more usual that in that situation, where one prays as the voice of a group, the plural form is preferred: "Te pedimos/te suplicamos".

The rest (except for the missing accent noted by Emilio) is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Although "oro" is correct, I would say "yo rezo para" for the translation of "...I pray ...". It sounds better for me.

Comment: It is not a critic, it is a better translation. And it is an answer to the question because she ask of a sugestion of improvements, and I did sugest something to improve the translation.

Comment: And I cannot write a comment because I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: Es automatico...no te preocupes

Answer (score 0):

I agree, oro seems a little bit unnecessary, you could say
Amado Señor, que el Espíritu Santo permanezca con todos nosotros

and the fact that you are praying for is determined by the context.